# Replace every texts except html tag inside DIV Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I'm trying to replace all the text in a DIV, including inside children without change any html tags. In my example, I would like to change all the 'Hello' by 'Hi'. Thanks a lot.

```js
var changes = $('div').html().replace('Hello','Hi');

$('div').html(changes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="hello">Hello World</p>
  Hello World<br>
  <span class="world">Hello World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Andreas Not sure if that's really a dupe for this. `:)`

Comment: Hey @Bruno, do you want to reopen this question?

Comment: Have you found the solution? Is my solution working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `replace` with a string parameter is not capable of replacing more than once. You need RegEx with a `g` (global) flag to replace all.

```js
var changes = $('div').html().replace(/Hello/g,'Hi');
$('div').html(changes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="hello">Hello World</p>
  Hello World<br>
  <span class="world">Hello World</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I would also add `i` to the regex (`/Hello/gi`) so it's case insensitive - if that fits your needs

Comment: Agreed with @Jamesonthedog... If it needs case sensitivity.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, my problem was to have used .text() instead of .html()